# Forzar SSL / https usando .htaccess

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, ssl, https

La pagina esta montada por WAMP

Punto # 1 si escribo:

`http://my-site.com`

Tenerlo redirigido a

`https://my-site.com`

.htaccess

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule`

application/config/config.php

$config['base_url'] = 'https://my-site.com/';
```

Answer (score 3):

Así es como tengo actualmente configurado `.htaccess` en mi dominio

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://misitio.com/$1 [R,L,NC]

Options All -Indexes
```

Probado en un entorno real y funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de tu `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

```
### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# Enforce SSL https://www. 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Mira que no funciona cuando cambio en el navegdor para hacer pruebas de que funciona y le coloco http en vez de https para ver si lo cambia y tira esto                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                   Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.

Comment: Perdón, sólo copia de nuevo lo que acabo de editar, se me fueron otras cosas.

Comment: Sólo son necesarias las 4 primeras líneas

Comment: `Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>` lo hago de esta forma y no me funciona que hago mal